# Step-like correlation. Is that possible?

Tags: correlation, partial-correlation

I have a problem analyzing two variables of my experiments. Variable 1 is the Signal to noise ratio, that is the relevance of my signal of interest with respect to the noise, just a noise measure. Variable 2 is the score, the precision of my algorithm. I have seen that when the SNR is low, the algorithm very usually shows a low precision, and for high SNR it shows very good precision. However, from my experimental data, that is not very clear, and I don't know how to demonstrate that correlation because in the correlation plot, it looks like a step-like scatter.

Here is the picture
[image]

To be honest, when I looked at the specific experiments with the low SNR , the signals are also a bit weird, but they most probably show a low score.

Do you think this could infers a correlation between the two variables or the possible explanation is that there is no real SCORE-SNR correlation but it is more probable for signals with low SNR to have abnormal results?

Thank you